# How can we identify if a method belongs to an abstract class or an interface?

Tags: java

How can we identify whether a particular method belongs to an abstract class or an interface? Is there any way to identify it or not?

Comment: just thinking, where in real world this scenario will come that you want to know the method belongs from interface or abstract class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only valid answer on this question should be:

You do not want to know that. If you need to know that, there is something wrong with your classes design.

But nevertheless you can do it via reflection for interfaces at least.

Be careful with your first try, because this will return `false`, even if it is declared in an interface of the class. (See example below)

```
TestImpl.class.getMethod("test").getDeclaringClass().isInterface(); // false
```

You will need to do more reflection magic to get the correct result like this:

```
public class ReflectionTest {

interface Test {
    void test();
}

class TestImpl implements Test {

    @Override
    public void test() {
    }

}

private static boolean isInterfaceMethod(Class clazz, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    for (Class interfaze : clazz.getMethod(methodName).getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()) {
        for (Method method : interfaze.getMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println(isInterfaceMethod(TestImpl.class, "test")); // true
    }
}
```